# Validar XML com o XSD gerado a partir de uma Classe

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Como posso validar corretamente o meu XML atrvés de um XSD que foi automaticamente gerado com base numa classe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gerar automaticamente um XSD é um mau caminho, porém às vezes é necessário.

O melhor caminho passa sempre por criar o nosso XSD manualmente para definir melhor as regras e restrições assim garantimos que validação é bem sucedida.